# Devolver datos inexistentes con 0 en la consulta de una tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
sql= SELECT p.programa, u.programapms,p.status,COUNT(p.status) AS estatus,  COUNT(p.programa) AS total FROM escrituracion p INNER JOIN programapms u ON p.programa= u.programapms WHERE status=1 GROUP BY programa
```

Ese es el resultado, estoy trayendo los que tienen el status 1 pero hay otros programas que no tienen registros con el status 1 entonces quiero que me muestre el programa con algún status 0 y un total de 0

Resultado de la conulta:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yVkL.png)]

Quisera el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: WHERE statuS que?? Puedes poner ese filtro o mejor dicho toda la query bien detallada...

Comment: si disculpa es status=1 ya modifique la consulta

Comment: Bueno, entonces no incluyas status en el WHERE o incluyes ambos **WHERE status IN (0, 1)**

Comment: LO QUE PASA 1QUE NO TENGO NINGUN REGISTRO CON STATUS 0 EN EL PROGRAMA2 ENTONCES QUIERO QUE ME DEVUELVA LOS VALORES EN 0 NO SE SI SE PUEDA

Comment: Intenta con `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @santiagoRivera, si no hay status cero, entonces que otros status tienes? Si solo tienes status 1 el WHERE esta demás. Sin la estructura de ambas tablas es difícil replicar aunque puedes probar con otros Joins como ya te dijeron...

Comment: si tengo otros tengo otros estatus  1,2,3,4,5 pero en programa2 no tengo ningun registro con el status 1